# From Classic ASP consume a ssl .net web service

Tags: web-services, ssl, asp-classic, https, asmx

I've researched the web extensively before posting this questions here, couldn't find anything usefull for me, so here it goes. Sorry in advance for the wall of text.

I have a classic ASP website that needs to call a web service method (not wcf, but an asmx page) on a asp.net website (4.0)

The way I consume the web service is as follows:

I have a webserviceclass.asp that helps me consume web services in classic asp.

code of webserviceclass.asp -> https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1Wr1Kw74xy3ZkducEtiTWNtWDA/edit?usp=sharing

Then calling the class to consume the method.

```
Dim strWebServiceResult
Dim ws
Set ws = new webservice
ws.url = "http://www.myurl.com/mywebservice.asmx"
ws.method = "HelloWorld"

ws.parameters.Add "Parameter1", "Test1"
ws.parameters.Add "Parameter2", "Test2"

ws.Execute

strWebServiceResult = ws.response
```

This works perfectly if www.myurl.com is not encrypted, strWebServiceResult holds the XML returned by mywebservice.asmx, however I really need the data traveling between the users and www.myurl.com to be encrypted (mywebservice.asmx has parameters for login and password to authenticate on the webservice) so I bought an SSL cert and assigned it to www.myurl.com website becoming https://www.myurl.com

So when I set the URL in the class to: `ws.url = "https://www.myurl.com/mywebservice.asmx"`
and that is the only thing that changes, the method doesn't get called anymore. I have log on pageinit and pageload of the mywebservice.aspx and it doesn't even get called.

Sorry about the long text, and I hope someone can help me. I have no experience with jquery or json and I'd rather not go that way to solve this problem, but if that's the only way, I can try if there's enough info out there to help me out but I'd rather try to fix my current code if that possible. I just don't understand why it works with http but not with https

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In this SO question ("[Can't use HTTPS with ServerXMLHTTP object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212985/cant-use-https-with-serverxmlhttp-object)"), this issue was addressed.

For a starter, you should be using "MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP" instead of "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" on the server side. This is discussed here, f.i.: [differences between Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP and WinHttp.WinHttpRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163045/differences-between-msxml2-serverxmlhttp-and-winhttp-winhttprequest)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, as soon as I saw I got very excited and tried it straight way.
I changed this line "Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")" to this "Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")", added this line "xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", SOAP_NS + "/" & SOAP_FUNCTION" and this line "xmlhttp.setOption(2) = 13056" to my class and tried again but no luck. Still same behavior, no errors or anything, web service simply doesn't get called.

Comment: Even with changes from my last comment, if I remove the https to http, it works, which means the new code also works, like the old one. But nothing makes it work with https