# JScript (WSH) get data from server. which ActiveXObject to use

Tags: javascript, httprequest, jscript, activexobject

Well I have a small piece of JScript code that responsible to download data from a server (binary data as well):

```
var HttpObj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
HttpObj.open("GET", serverUrl, false);
HttpObj.send();
var responseText = HttpObj.responseText;
```

This code work fine, However, initializing `HttpObj` as:

```
var HttpObj = new ActiveXObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1");
```

also works.

As I see it, there are quite a few `ActiveXObject` object that provide HTTP requests API.

#### Question

Which `ActiveXObject` to use? which one is the "best" / latest / most robust / fits most cases? How do I even begin evaluating that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [differences between Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP and WinHttp.WinHttpRequest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163045/differences-between-msxml2-serverxmlhttp-and-winhttp-winhttprequest)

Comment: @Helen I looked at that post. I do not agree since it is very specific question about two objects. My question is more generic and apply to any multiple `ActiveXObject` objects with similar API. even If we do agree that it is duplicated, the answers provided do not give me the tools to evaluate such cases in the future.